# Not able viewing image using image_view package

Tags: ros-kinetic, image-view, ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to use image_view to to view bottom camera of ardrone simulated in Gazebo but not able to see anything. The below command I've used:

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/ardrone/bottom/image_raw
```

The gui of camera is just appeared for about 3 seconds before it freezes. I have just upgraded to OpenCV3 anyway. Has it something to do with OpenCV3?

Anything that could go wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281022/not-able-viewing-image-using-image_view-package/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2018-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found out that after reinstalling the ROS solves the issue by running the following command along with setting up the appropriate ROS environment variables:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

---

Originally posted by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) with karma: 1053 on 2018-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0